# Does maven maintain any setting cache?

Tags: maven

I comment out my local repository section  im my pom.xml, but when I ran `mvn eclipse: eclipse`, it still try to download plugin from local repository. I also check the pom.xml it depends on and make sure to comment out them either, but this problem still occurs.

I think I might neglect some setting?

Answer (score 0):

You may have a `settings.xml` in the default maven repository location `.m2`. If you are running maven inside eclipse, check your maven configuration inside Eclipse preferences, there you should find the location of the `settings.xml` file.

Comment: Well, re-reading your question. Maven always try to find the artifacts first from the local repository, if you don't define one it will go to the default one. If what you want to do is prevent maven from going to your default local repository, you have either to rename the existing one, or define a different one in settings or pom.